# How to create multiple JSON array

Tags: java, json

I was looking this for creating JSON and the output is

{
    "age":100,
    "name":"mkyong.com",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]
}

But i want an array of 10 times like this

```
{
        "engine": "Trident",
        "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
        "platform": "Win 95+",

    },
    {
        "engine": "Trident",
        "browser": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
        "platform": "Win 95+",

    },
    {
        "engine": "Trident",
        "browser": "Internet Explorer 5.5",
        "platform": "Win 95+",

    },
```

And this is the way I tried

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class TestJson {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject obj=null;
         obj = new JSONObject();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

    obj.put("engine", "mkyong.com");
    obj.put("browser", i);
obj.put("platform", i);



    //obj.put("messages", list);
    }
    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("c:\\test.json");
        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(obj);

     }

}
```

but this only prints 1 json

```
{
        "engine": "Trident",
        "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
        "platform": "Win 95+",

    }
```

Comment: You want a JSON array but you are using a `JSONObject`...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the reply.How to create 10 times like the example

Comment: @Deepak as suggested: create `JSONArray` and add to it what you want

Comment: I've done the same in C# if you will say i can explain the logic in the answer. the logic is like create a list of object and then add an new item to the list each and every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("engine", "mkyong.com");
    obj.put("browser", i);
    obj.put("platform", i);

    //if you are using JSON.simple do this
    array.add(obj);

    //and if you use json-jena
    array.put(obj);
}
jsonObject.put("MyArray" , array);

System.out.print(jsonObject);
```

Comment: `JSONArray` does not have a `put` method.

Comment: check this [link](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONArray.html) out and you will find the `put` method.

Comment: yes it does not have a put method but when i changed it to add,it worked.Sorry i do not have enough reputations to upvote

Comment: `array.put(obj);` should be `array.add(obj);`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: thanks for reminding I just updated my answer. the code is the same for both except the `put` and `add`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code

```
JSONObject obj=null;
obj = new JSONObject();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

    obj.put("engine", "mkyong.com");
    obj.put("browser", i);
    obj.put("platform", i);

    //obj.put("messages", list);
}
```

you are creating a single `JSONObject` and overwriting its values 10 times.

Why are you working with a `JSONObject` when you want a JSON array?

Create a [`JSONArray`](http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html) and add 10 `JSONObject` objects to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I didnt understand you.Can you give an example please?

Comment: @Deepak What don't you understand? An example won't help if you don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Deepak Good stuff. I recommend you go through the [different data types](http://www.json.org/) that JSON supports.

Comment: I do not have enough reputations to upvote your answer but I promise I will do when I have it later.Thanks again for the answer

Comment: @deepak Don't worry about that. But please don't ask for solutions right off the bat. Try to understand what you are _doing_ and what you are _trying to do_. The solution will often come on its own.